# How to count the number of distinct users that meet a certain condition using CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server

In short, I'm working with medical claims data and I'm trying to figure out the total number of patients (`patient_id`) that have two or more diagnosis codes (`diag_code`) of interest.

The `medical_claims` table looks something like this:

```
claim_id | patient_id | icd_code
---------+------------+---------
01       | 111         | 150
02       | 111         | 200
03       | 222         | 150
04       | 222         | 1999
05       | 333         | 150
06       | 333         | 200
07       | 333         | 205
08       | 333         | 210
```

I want to only include distinct `patient_id`'s that have >=2 of any one of `icd_code` = 150, 200, 205, 210. The resulting output would include only `patient_id` = 111 and 333

I think CASE WHEN is probably the most efficient approach, but not sure how exactly to get this set up correctly.

I'm currently trying to build it out like this, but it just gives me the distribution of the different `icd_code` values:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN icd_code = '150' then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "150",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN icd_code = '200'  then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "200",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN icd_code = '205'  then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "205",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN icd_code = '210'  then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "210"
FROM medical_claims
```

Comment: So if a given patient has 2 rows of ICD = 150, you would include or exclude that patient?

Comment: That's actually a really good point. What would that look like if that condition was included/excluded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to only include distinct patient_id's that have >=2 of any one of icd_code = 150, 200, 205, 210.

You can use aggregation and `having`:

```
select mc.patient_id
from medical_claims mc
where mc.icd_code in (150, 200, 205, 210)
group by mc.patient_id
having count(distinct mc.icd_code) >= 2;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! How can I make this count the total number of distinct patient_id with >=2 icd_code values?

Comment: @David . .  You would use this query as a CTE or subquery and use `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I tried running a subquery with COUNT(*) and couldn't get it to work. Could you show me how you would go about this? Thank you again!

Comment: @David . . . I don't understand your comment.  Are you saying this doesn't work?

Comment: When I tried using a COUNT(*) as a subquery, I kept getting an error. I tried to few different ways, but I think I'm setting it up incorrectly

Comment: @David . . . Perhaps you should ask a new question.  This answer has neither `count(*)` nor a subquery so I may not understand the comment.

Comment: When I run your solution, it returns all of the `patient_id` values that meet the WHERE condition. I wanted to count the total number of `patient_id`. That's where I tried using count(*), but wasn't sure exactly how to build this into a subquery as you mentioned.

Comment: Never mind, I now see what you were getting at with the count(*). Thank you for your help!